# Need help, created code and accumulator isn't counting the uppercase letters in a text file

Tags: python

I need to create a program for my python class that counts how many words are in a text file. It also needs to count how many uppercase characters there are in the text file.

I've tried about everything that I know of. I've used the book and I've emailed my professor but he hasn't gotten back to me yet and I don't expect a response anytime soon.

```
filename = input("Enter the name of the file you wish to process: ")

upperWord = 0
numWords = 0
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        wordsList = line.split()
        numWords += len(wordsList)
    for upperCase in f:
        if upperCase.isupper():
            upperWord += 1

print('The file', filename, 'contains', numWords, 'words of which', upperWord, 'of them are capitalized.')
```

The print statement at the end will print as follows:
'The file sample.txt contains 149 words of which 0 of them are capitalized'
There should be 49 capitalized words in this text file. 
So the print statement should print as follows:
'The file sample.txt contains 149 words of which 59 of them are capitalized'

Comment: You can't loop twice from a file handle without resetting the file pointer. Rethink your approach.

Comment: Just a design tip: Have a look into list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you think `for upperCase in f` will do.

The first loop, `for line in f`, iterates over the whole file. After this loop, the file is finished; you can't iterate over it again (without resetting the pointer).

But what you actually want to do is to iterate over each word in each line. So your second loop should be nested within the for loop, and should loop over the list of words that you just created:

```
for line in f:
    wordsList = line.split()
    numWords += len(wordsList)
    for word in wordsList:
        if word.isupper():
            upperWord += 1
```

(Also, just to check the requirements: `word.isupper()` will only return true if the entire word is in capitals. Is that what you need? Or do you need to check if the word only contains any capital letters?)

**Edit**

If you want to check for individual capitals, you will need to iterate over the line again:

```
for line in f:
  wordsList = line.split()
  numWords += len(wordsList)
  for character in line:
    if character.isupper():
      upperWord += 1
```

Comment: I need it to count how many uppercase characters there are in the text file. So I don't know how I would go about creating that inside the first for loop to loop over the list of words that I created

Comment: But you want the output to say "149 words, of which 49 are capitalized". So which is it? Number of words in all capitals, or overall number of capital letters?

Comment: The final output needs to display the number of words in the text document and how many characters in the text document are capitalized. For example, if the text document had 200 words, and for some reason theres only 27 capitalized characters in the text document, the final output would say there are 200 words and 27 of them are capitalized. Sorry this is so specific, these are just the requirements asked from my professor.

Comment: Fair enough. I understand that English isn't your first language, but here "27 of them* clearly refers to "words", so this says "200 words including 27 capitalized words". What you want to say is "200 words, including 27 capital letters". Anyway, I updated the answer.

Comment: I'd like to apologize for being really dumb earlier. I did not realize that you actually gave me the answer. A little hurt that you said that  English isn't my first language when it is. I was so overwhelmed with college homework and I was in such a rush that I didn't even notice you made a change to my code and fixed it for me in the edit. Sorry for making this much more complicated than it was. Thank you very much though! I under stand it now :)